# python sum of pair of a list using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to write a lambda function that accepts a list and returns a list with the sum of pair of number in list with their index details.

Example

```
input: [4,5,1]
output: [(0,1,9),(0,2,5),(1,2,6)]
in the above example we do pairwise sum 

 1. (4,5) --> 9
 2. (4,1) --> 5
 3. (5,1) --> 6
```

nested loop solution

```
def sumpair(L):
 result=[]
 for i in range(len(L)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
   result.append((i,j,L[i]+L[j]))
 return result
```

I know how to write it using nested for loop, wanted to know if it is possible to write this using lambda if not, I wanted to understand what kind of functionality we can write using lambda?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this?  For example, your nested loop solution?

Comment: @ScottHunter added nested loop solution

Comment: You could write a lambda that calls your `sumpair` function, but that might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas and for-loops are not mutually exclusive. You could put a list comprehension inside your lambda and call it a day:

```
compute = lambda L: [(i, j, L[i]+L[j]) for i,j in itertools.combinations(range(len(L)), 2)]
```

(don't forget to `import itertools`). Then you'd get

```
In [12]: compute([4,5,1])
Out[12]: [(0, 1, 9), (0, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6)]
```

On the other hand, if you didn't want to make a new variable:

```
(lambda L: [(i, j, L[i]+L[j]) for i,j in itertools.combinations(range(len(L)), 2)])([4,5,1])
```

would give you the same result